# How to read QWORD (64-bit) from the registry in C++?

Tags: c++, dword

How do I read a REG_QWORD from the registry? Most specifically the HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize .
I found that with it divided by 1024 then once again divided by 1024 you can get the Video memory in megabytes. How can I read the QWORD first? I can only find how to read DWORDs.

Comment: Pass `REG_QWORD` for the type to be read - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read a `QWORD` the exact same way you read a `DWORD`, using [`RegQueryValueEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexw), just with a 64-bit integer variable instead of a 32-bit integer variable, eg:

```cpp
HKEY hKey;
if (RegOpenKeyEx(..., KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    QWORD value = 0; // or UINT64, ULONGLONG, ULONG64, ULARGE_INTEGER, etc...
    DWORD dwType, dwSize = sizeof(value);

    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, _T("HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"), NULL, &dwType, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&value), &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        if (dwType == REG_QWORD || dwType == REG_BINARY) {
            // use value as needed...
        }
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Or, using [`RegGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew) instead:

```cpp
QWORD value = 0; // see above...
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(value);

if (RegGetValue(hkey, NULL, _T("HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"), RRF_RT_QWORD, NULL, &value, &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // use value as needed...
}
```

Comment: For me QWORD is undefined, I don't know why...

Comment: I think I defined it as follows:

Comment: ```typedef unsigned __int64 QWORD;```

Comment: @JackRivera "*QWORD is undefined*" - it depends on the version of the Windows SDK you have installed. Maybe you have an older version? Per [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types): `typedef unsigned __int64 QWORD;` There are many different aliases for `(unsigned) __int64` defined by the Win32 API, ie `DWORDLONG`, `DWORD64`, `(U)INT64`, `(U)LONGLONG`, `(U)LONG64`, `(U)LARGE_INTEGER`, etc. Use whichever one works for you, or just use `(unsigned) __int64` directly.

Comment: I went up and down through your answer and the Top solution did it for me. Thank you very much take my correct answer tick for appreciation.